# Скрыть классы data-option которых хранятся в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив `["XL", "L"]` и кнопки:

```
<label data-option="XL" class="label">XL</label>
<label data-option="L" class="label">XL</label>
<label data-option="M" class="label">XL</label>
<label data-option="2XL" class="label">XL</label>
```

Нужна функция, которая будет скрывать нужные `label`. Написал функцию но она скрывает первый найденный элемент, а нужно чтобы все

```
$.each(array, function (index, value) {
        $('.label').css('display', 'inline-block'); // включаем все элементы
        $('.label[data-option="' + value + '"]').css('display', 'none'); // выключаем нужный
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А у тебя разве в каждой итерации цикла не происходит "Включение всех элементов"?

```
$('.label').css('display', 'inline-block'); // включаем все элементы
```

Попробуй вынести вот это за .each.

Comment: Так и есть спасибо!